# C# DataTable vs Some generic collection performance

Tags: c#, generics, datatable, boxing, unboxing

I know that the `DataTable` is using boxing/unboxing  when we are inserting/getting the data. If we have a really big amount of data containing only `int`'s for example, isn't it faster to use some sort of generic `DataTable` , let's say `MyDataTable<int>`, which will result in avoiding boxing/unboxing overhead?

Answer (score 3):

Strings are reference-types, so there is no boxing overhead: they are never boxed. DataTable does have plenty of overheads though - that is the cost of being able to represent arbitrary column models along with constraints, change-tracking, etc. For optimum performance, a POCO model is hard to beat. For example:

```
public class Customer {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

There are plenty of ORMs and micro-ORMs that make working with this type of model.

Note, however, that in DataTable, the values are *stored* in correctly-typed arrays. Ints are stored in an int[] - which is does by storing data in columns rather than rows. Boxing only happens when getting data into/out-of the DataTable.

Answer (score 2):

The primary issue that you'll need to deal with is that a `DataTable` can have any number of columns in which each column can be of any type.  You can't genericize it while still having different types for each column.

One way you can avoid the boxing is to, rather than using a `DataTable`, create an object to represent each row.  Ensure that the object has a property for each column of the appropriate type.  You can then work with a `List` (or some other data structure) of those objects.

Another option, if you have, for example, entirely `int` values for your data, would be to create a multi-dimentional array of ints (`int[,] mydata = new int[10000,5];`).  That would also avoid boxing the integers.